# ASP.NET Core 2.2 PWA offline

Tags: asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps

I Have ASP.NET Core project and want to make it work also with PWA and it needs to work also offline.

I know there are prefetch and preload options but i'm little bit confused

How to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: The get started button here will walk you through the things needed to create a PWA. https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I have already researched those links but problem is that app should download/cache whole website at start or when app is installing. How can i achieve that? When i visit that specific route then yes its caches everything whats related to that route. And when i visit that route offline works fine.

Comment: It would be hard for anyone to explain how to make your website work in a specific way without seeing how you have constructed it. Try making it work using what you know then post problems here with code so people can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

First, the PWA and the service worker itself are decouple from the server, which in your case is ASP.NET.

As far as what you cache and how that is all up to you. You need to determine what is best for your user experience.

In a way, the service worker can be thought of as a web server and you have to code the application layer to manage your requests.

DO NOT go nuts and try to recreate your ASP.NET and all the server logic in the service worker. Not what you should do there. Seen that too many times already.

I have an article covering basic service worker caching concepts if that helps.
https://love2dev.com/blog/service-worker-cache/

Comment: This article might also be helpful
https://love2dev.com/serviceworker/development-best-practices/